# Trouble in printing values of BinarySearchTree in pre order traversal

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

```
public class BinarySearchTree<E extends Comparable<E>> implements BinaryTree<E>
{
    BinaryTree<E> left = new EmptyBinarySearchTree<E>();
    BinaryTree<E> right = new EmptyBinarySearchTree<E>();
    E value;
    public BinarySearchTree (E value){
        this.value = value;
    }
    public boolean containsKey(E value){
        boolean result = false;
        int cmp = value.compareTo(this.value);
        if(cmp == 0) 
            result = true;
        if(cmp < 0) 
            result = left.containsKey(value);
        if(cmp > 0) 
            result = right.containsKey(value);
        return result;
    }
    public BinaryTree<E> add(E value){
        int cmp = value.compareTo(this.value);
        if(cmp<0)
            left = left.add(value);
        if(cmp>0)
            right = right.add(value);   
        return this;
    }
    public E get(E value){
        int cmp = value.compareTo(this.value);
        if(cmp == 0) return this.value;
        if(cmp < 0) return left.get(value);
        if(cmp > 0) return right.get(value);
        return this.value;
    }
    public BinaryTree<E> getLeft(){
        return left;
    }
    public BinaryTree<E> getRight(){
        return right;
    }
    public E getValue(){
        return value;
    }
    /**
     * Change the value of this BinaryTree to the given value
     */
    public void setValue(E value){
        this.value = value;
    }
    /**
     * Set the left child of this BinaryTree to the given BinaryTree
     */
    public void setLeft(BinaryTree<E> left){
        this.left = left;
    }
    /**
     * Set the right child of this BinaryTree to the given BinaryTree
     */
    public void setRight(BinaryTree<E> right){
        this.right = right;
    }
    public String toPreOrderString(){
        String result = "" + value + ",";
        result += left.toPreOrderString();
        result += right.toPreOrderString();
        return result;
    }
```

Problem is with `toPreOrderString()` method. For instance when I call this method on a certain set of data i get the following output:

```
kimmy,jimmy,al,[][]joe,jo,[][][]susie,sue,[][][]
```

How can I adjust my method to make the output look like the following:

```
[kimmy,jimmy,al,joe,jo,susie,sue]
```

I can't figure it out.Please help.

Comment: in `toPreOrderString()` check left and right if one is `instanceof EmptyBinarySearchTree`, and if one is, don't append it to output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if `left` or `right` is an `EmptyBinarySearchTree` and if so, don't recurse.

Comment: Easy fix :) You may also want to consider using if-else if-else statements instead of if-if-if

Answer (score 0):

check if left or right is an EmptyBinarySearchTree in the method, only proceed if it isn't.